# DocumentViewer toolbar and context menu

Tags: .net, wpf, controls, customization

How to hide the default toolbar and to disallow the default context menu of the `DocumentViewer` control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent the default context menu from appearing by handling the `ContextMenuOpening` event, and setting `ContextMenuEventArgs.Handled` to true.

As for the toolbar, I'm not sure - maybe you could somehow change the default style of the DocumentView to not include the toolbar? I haven't ever done much with styles, but that is probably where I'd start looking.

Answer (score 9):

You can hide (or change) the toolbar by creating a control template for DocumentViewer without the toolbar.

start with the sample template from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970452(v=vs.100) and add and remove things until you are happy with the results.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff - fixed the link, MS no longer publishes control templates on MSDN for .net 4.5 so I had to choose .net 4 from the previous versions menu, the new link is hard-coded for .net 4 (at least until MS change their URLs)

Answer (score 5):

You can just set the ContextMenu property to null like this:

```
<DocumentViewer ContextMenu="{x:Null}"/>
```