# Change WPF DocumentViewer viewing mode

Tags: wpf, documentviewer

Hello I've got the problem that when I just add a `<DocumentViewer x:Name="docViewer" />` I get a toolbar what allow me to change the viewing mode of the XPS document like here:
[image]

But how can I do this programmatically?
I cant find any property that do this and the MSDN and Google say nothing about this feature.
Then I found the `FlowDocumentReader` control what have a `ViewingMode` property, however it can't display a XPS document. I can't believe that it is not possible to do this, I mean that function is available by default, I just want to change it programmatically...

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201875/documentviewer-toolbar-and-context-menu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DocuementViewer didn't exposed any property to change the ViewMode. But in case you want to change the ViewMode programmatically, you can execute the commands exposed by DocumentViewer which are as -

- DocumentViewer.FitToWidthCommand
- DocumentViewer.FitToHeightCommand
- DocumentViewer.FitToMaxPagesAcrossCommand

You can bind these commands to your custom button or programmatically you can change the ViewMode. Suppose you have a `DocuementViewer` named `documentViewer`, you can call these methods on this instance like this -

- documentViewer.FitToWidth()
- documentViewer.FitToHeight()
- documentViewer.FitToMaxPagesAcross()